# How would one setup a custom filter for their JSON in PHP using FullCalendar?

Tags: php, json, filter, fullcalendar

Does anyone know how to filter the posts shown on fullcalendar based on their custom fields?

Example: If I wanted to only show "media == twitter" how would I be able to accomplish this using only one json feed?

I appreciate any ideas.

**Example of Json:**

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "title": "Title",
    "description": "Details",
    "media": "twitter",
},
{
    "id": "2",
    "title": "Title",
    "description": "Details",
    "media": "linkedin",
},
{
    "id": "3",
    "title": "Title",
    "description": "Details",
    "media": "facebook",
}
```

The following is the basic setup I have so far of the fullcalendar which is currently working fine.

**Example of FullCalendar code:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        defaultDate: '<? echo '2015-11-01'; ?>',
        editable: false,
        events: "json.php",

        eventClick: function(event) {
        if (event.url) {

        window.open('#' + event.id,"_self");

        return false;
            }
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to above mentioned description as a solution to filter json feed,you need to decode json data into php associative array using json_decode() function and apply filter for specific data while iterating over an associative array.

Please refer the example code snippet to filter json data

```
 <?php  $json_data='[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "title": "Title",
        "description": "Details",
        "media": "twitter"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "title": "Title",
        "description": "Details",
        "media": "linkedin"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "title": "Title",
        "description": "Details",
        "media": "facebook"
    }
]';
       $result=NULL;
       $json_array=json_decode($json_data,true);
       if($json_array)
       {
          foreach($json_array as $json)
          {
              switch($json['media'])
              {
                 case 'twitter':
                 $result=$json;
                 break;
              }
          }
       }
      echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

$result variable will hold the filtered json data.

Comment: Thanks for your help Rubin, after customizing my json data it worked great. Is there a way to grab multiple media's? If for example id 2 and id 3 have media twitter as well it doesn't seem to pull the others? Would I add a loop to this or something to allow that to work?

Comment: Thanks @Matt for accepting answer.Regarding your concern to grab multiple medias you need to define $result in above code snippet as an array and the above code snippet will work fine for multiple filters